# Delete Blank lines on Visual Basic Export txt

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to export a txt file with the rows and columns of an excel File,
The point is that i always get and extra line in blank and i dont want it, is there a way to do so?

This is my code

```
Sub Creatxt()

Dim NombreArchivo, RutaArchivo As String
Dim obj As FileSystemObject
Dim tx As Scripting.TextStream
Dim ht As Worksheet
Dim i, j, nFilas, nColumnas As Integer

NombreArchivo = "OPG"
RutaArchivo = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NombreArchivo & ".txt"

Set obj = New FileSystemObject
Set tx = obj.CreateTextFile(RutaArchivo)
Set ht = Worksheets("Datos")

nFilas = ht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
nFilas = nFilas - 7
nColumnas = ht.Range("A8", ht.Range("A8").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count

For i = 1 To nFilas
    For j = 1 To nColumnas
        
      tx.Write ht.Cells(i + 7, j)
      If j < nColumnas Then tx.Write vbTab

        
    Next j
    tx.WriteLine
    
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `If i < nFilas Then tx.WriteLine`  ?

Answer (score 0):

`CreateTextFile` place a vbCrLf at the end of the file content when the stream is closed and saved.
When all contents are added to the stream apply the `Close` method, because otherwise there is an astonishing result with the created file.

```
For i = 1 To nFilas
    For j = 1 To nColumnas
        
      tx.Write ht.Cells(i + 7, j)
      If j < nColumnas Then tx.Write vbTab

        
    Next j
    If Not i=nFilas then tx.WriteLine
    
Next i
tx.Close
End Sub
```